# IncrementalLoadingCollection loading all items right away in ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp, infinite-scroll

I'm writing an UWP app in C#. I have a page with a ListView taking all space available.

The list of items is huge so I use `IncrementalLoadingCollection` to load items gradually in the ListView while user is scrolling.

The problem is when I start the app all items are loaded right away in the ListView. `GetPagedItemsAsync` is called over and over and the app crashes throwing `Layout cycle detected`.

The only way I get the scroll loading to work is by fixing the ListView or height to a certain value. With fixed height on the ListView `GetPagedItemsAsync` is only called once at initialization and the scroll loading works as expected.

The thing is I want the ListView to fill page content so I don't want to set height to a specific value.

**Page content**

```
<Grid 
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

    <ListView 
        x:Name="channelList" 
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind Channels}"
        DataFetchSize="100" 
        IncrementalLoadingTrigger="Edge" 
        IncrementalLoadingThreshold="5" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

**Page class**

```
public sealed partial class ChannelsPage : Page
{
    private IncrementalLoadingCollection<ChannelSource, ChannelModel> Channels { get; set; }

    public ChannelsPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Channels = new IncrementalLoadingCollection<ChannelSource, ChannelModel>();
    }

    private class ChannelSource : IIncrementalSource<ChannelModel>
    {
        private int Current { get; set; } = 0;
        private int Limit { get; set; } = 100;
        public async Task<IEnumerable<ChannelModel>> GetPagedItemsAsync(int pageIndex, int pageSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            List<ChannelModel> channels = ChannelModel.List(false, Limit, Current);
            Current += Limit;
            return channels;
        }
    }
}
```

[Solved]
The `ListView` was expanding out of bound due to a parent `ScrollViewer` in another file. Because of this continuous expansion out of its parent the items was loading non-stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to unlocking this mystery is the `IncrementalLoadingThreshold`. In simple terms it says the system how many "pages" of content to preload. In case you use 5, the system will make sure to have 5 times the height of the control ready to view. Try decreasing the value to 1 and you should see the method will be called once or twice. Even lower values like 0.1 are also possible.

Secondly, ensure you do not put the `ListView` into any layout control which allows it to expand beyond any bounds. For example, putting the list in a `Grid.Row` which has `RowDefinition` of `Height="*"` will make the list as long as it needs - which means it will keep loading items until there are no more available.

Finally, you need to make sure to indicate when you are out of items. This is easy if you return an empty `IEnumerable` from the method.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Setting `IncrementalLoadingThreshold` to 1 did not fixed the issue. It may have to do with the ListView container like you said. How can I force the ListView to stay in it's parent bounds? I thought `Stretch` alignments would help but it didn't.

Comment: Is the XAML code you sent the exact code you use? Or is the layout more complex? I have tried the sample and it worked for me after setting the threshold to something low. Also I didn't even get the layout errors, so I suspect something must be different about your case :-)

Comment: Thank you Martin, I finally fixed it! Like you suspected there was a `ScrollViewer` chilling in the parent `MainPage`, allowing the `ListView` to expand out of bounds. Regards

Comment: I'm glad it helped :-)!